# Day 1 of programming: Problem with \n in C

Tags: c, codeblocks

This is about a super small issue but I can't seem to get a new line started as my book is showing me. (C Programming An absolute beginners guide by Perry and Miller) I'll paste my code below.

The last word, said, is supposed to be on a separate line but for some reason the \n there isn't working. To be fair this book is based on Code::Blocks 10.05 so it could be a formatting issue?

```
    // Absolute Beginner's Guide to C, 3rd Edition
    // Chapter 4 Example 1--Chapter4ex3.c

    

    #include <stdio.h>

    main()

    {

    /* These three lines show you how to use the most popular Escape

    Sequences */

    printf("Column A\tColumn B\tColumn C");

    printf("\nMy Computer\'s Beep Sounds Like This: \a!\n");

    printf("\"Letz\bs fix that typo and then show the backslash ");

    printf("character \\\" she said\n");


    return 0;

    }
```

Comment: Welcome and thank you for your question. `printf("character \\\" she said\n");` puts the newline character *after* the word "said". If you want "said" to be on a new line, you need to put the newline character *before* the word "said".

Comment: That's what I was thinking, it may just be an outdated book?

Comment: Nope, it's more likely to be either a typo or a misunderstanding. I can't think of any old systems or environments where putting `\n` after "said" would put "said" on a new line by itself. For the future, it will be good to get into the habit of including expected and actual output when asking questions here.

Comment: https://imgur.com/gallery/BE5D1z3      Good call, thank you for reminding me. Side note 2 mins is a crazy fast response time. Thank you all!

Comment: Yep, based on that photo, said is only on the next line because there's no more space on the current line and the text wraps. Your terminal has more space so the word said fits without needing to wrap.

Comment: The newlines (`\n`) are all working. Remove them from all the printf functions and you should see all your output on the same line. Your expected result is more than likely text wrapping and therefore is bad publishing or a bad example by the author, due to the confusion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whenever you need something on a new line, you have to add \n just before that. So if you want 'said' on a new line, then add \n before 'said'. Like this     `printf("character \\\" she \nsaid");`

Comment: This totally works, but for my own piece of mind would you have a look at what the book says? I just wanna make sure I'm not missing a concept they're trying to get across. 
https://imgur.com/gallery/BE5D1z3

Comment: Hey! there is no problem or typo with the book. As it is mentioned in the book "You need to tweak(modify) the program to get the desired output". https://i.stack.imgur.com/c9zZU.png check this image. They purposefully have done that so you figure out where to place the "\n" and how to get the desired output. If you have any further doubts please add them here. Or if you're happy with the answer, you can accept the answer and close question. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
printf("character \\\" she said\n");
```

to

```
printf("character \\\" she \n said");
```

Actually, \n is the *escape sequence* for *next line*. Whenever the \n is displayed, it takes the cursor to the next line. So if you want to put the word **said** in a separate line, you must take the cursor to the next line before displaying it, which means you must print a \n before printing the word **said**.